# Access Matlab classes in MEX/C-code

Tags: c, matlab, oop, mex

I have to rewrite some matlab code into C which will then be embedded into Matlab using MEX once again. So far, I've read some tutorials and examples in how this works for simple data structures. (I've never done that before, even though I would consider myself experienced in both Matlab and C).

So here is the problem:

I have given something like that

```
classdef MyClass
     properties
          foo;
          bar;
          blub;
          somethingElse;
     end

     methods

          function obj = myFun(obj) % really just some random example code
               obj.foo = obj.bar;
               obj.blub = 42;
               for i = 1:length(obj.somethingElse)
                    obj.somethingElse(i) = i*i;
               end;
          end
     end
end
```

I want to rewrite myFun as a MEX/C-function. If I pass a class to a MEX-function, how can I access the different properties of this class?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the following functions in the MEX API:

> [mxGetProperty](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetproperty.html) and [mxSetProperty](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetproperty.html)

Their use is equivalent to:

```
value = pa[index].propname;

pa[index].propname = value;
```

Note that these functions create deep copies of the data. There are [undocumented functions](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-matlab-mex-api/#Property-access) to work with shared data.